# table variable creation in pyodbc / ceodbc

Tags: python, sql, t-sql, pyodbc

In both pyodbc and ceodbc, declaring a table variable, inserting some data into it, and then selecting from it doesn't seem to work.

```
cursor.execute("""
DECLARE @LOG TABLE 
    (ID varchar(10))

INSERT INTO @LOG (ID)

SELECT TOP 10 ID
FROM NAME

SELECT ID
FROM @LOG
""")

------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython console>", line 1, in <module>
ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.
```

I wonder if this is a real issue or there's a trick to make it work. SELECT statements always worked fine in my setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh. :oP

```
cursor.execute("""

SELECT ID
FROM 

(SELECT TOP 10 ID
FROM NAME)

LOG

""")

In [49]: cursor.fetchall()
Out[49]: 
[('1', ),
 ('10', ),
 ('100000', ),
 ('100001', ),
 ('100002', ),
 ('100003', ),
 ('100004', ),
 ('100005', ),
 ('100006', ),
 ('100007', )]
```